# Convergence series test failing using Sympy in Python: Is this a Bug?

Tags: python, math, symbolic-math

I tried testing for the convergence of an infinite series (Riemann Zeta function), which converges in the region that I am testing in (Dirichlet Series Section:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function)

The series (acc. to wiki) must converge. But Python says its divergent. So it this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

The python library I am using is sympy as follows:

```
from sympy import factorial, S, Sum, Symbol, oo
n = Symbol('n', integer=True)
Sum(n/(n+1)**.9 - (n-.9)/n**.9, (n, 1, oo)).is_convergent()
```